# I am trying to write Unit Test in C# for static methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am learning unit test for c# web application. I am stuck in above mention scenario. I am not sure if I am doing it in correct way. I have FakePath class for unit test. How do I write unit test for static method,Abc.log(), in MSTest?

```
public class Abc
{
    public static void log(string msg)
    {
        //Read on Write on path;
        string path = getPath(new ServerPath());
    }

    public static string getPath(IServerPath path)
    {
        return path.MapPath("file.txt");
    }
}

interface IServerPath()
{
    string MapPath(string file);
}

class ServerPath : IServerPath
{
    string MapPath(string file)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(file);
    }
}

class FakeServerPath : IServerPath
{
    string MapPath(string file)
    {
        return @"C:\"+file;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am just going to add that if you are writing a static method to write log entries, please use log4net. They have done all of the hard work for you.

Comment: I'd say Serilog in favor of log4net. Look at Structured Logging.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will look at serilog. In any case, I am sure either one is better than rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to test a void method, so one of your options of asserting this method is to verify if the method is called:

```
string expectedStr = "c:\file.txt";
[TestMethod]
public void FakeServerPath_VerifyMapPathWasCalled()
{
    var fakeServerPath = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<ServerPath>();
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeServerPath.MapPath("")).WillReturn(expectedStr);

    Abc.log("");

    Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithExactArguments(() => fakeServerPath.MapPath("file.txt"));
}
```

Another option is to test the return value of the `getPath(IServerPath path)` method, by modifying the return value of `ServerPath's` `MapPath(string file)` method to return a wanted value, and to assert if the return value is as expected.

```
string expectedStr = "c:\file.txt";
[TestMethod]
public void ModifyReturnValueFromMapPath_IsEqualToExpactedStr()
{
    var fakeServerPath = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<ServerPath>();

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeServerPath.MapPath("")).WillReturn(expectedStr);

    var result = Abc.getPath(fakeServerPath);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedStr, result);
}
```

Notice that by using [TypeMock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com) you will be able to fake the future instance of "ServerPath" without changing your original code.
And if necessary TypeMock is also able to mock `HttpContext` class as so:

```
string expectedStr = "c:\file.txt";
[TestMethod]
public void ModifyReturnValueFromHttpContext_IsEqualToExpactedStr()
{
    var serverPath = new ServerPath();

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("")).WillReturn(expectedStr);

    var result = Abc.getPath(serverPath);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedStr, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this you need to expose a way to set the dependency. Currently you are using a `new ServerPath()` directly in the method which makes it difficult to inject your `FakeServerPath` for testing.

You can modify `Abc`

```
public class Abc
{
    static Abc() { ServerPath = new ServerPath(); }

    public static IServerPath ServerPath { get; set; }

    public static void log(string msg) {
        //Read on Write on path;
        string path = getPath(ServerPath);
    }

    public static string getPath(IServerPath path) {
        return path.MapPath("file.txt");
    }
}
```

And a test could look like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void Abc_log_Test() {
    //Arrange
    string filename = "fakeFile.txt";
    string expected = @"C:\" + filename;
    var mockServerPath = new Mock<IServerPath>();
    mockServerPath
        .Setup(m => m.MapPath(filename))
        .Returns(expected)
        .Verifiable();
    Abc.ServerPath = mockServerPath.Object;
    var message = "Hello world";

    //Act
    Abc.log(message);

    //Assert
    mockServerPath.Verify();
}
```

Note I used Moq to mock up the server path

Answer (score 0):

Testing statics in itself is easy, just call them and assert on the results (the actual problem is testing code that *uses* statics, as they can't be mocked out). Testing in this particular case is complicated by a different thing.

The real problem of the `Log` method is that ti creates a `ServerPath` instance by itself, which precludes any chance of [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (on the contrary, the `GetPath` method is totally friendly to testing, as it takes an interface as a parameter).

I would introduce a refactoring on the `Abc` class to enable better testing on it. I would modify it as such:

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void Log(IServerPath path, string msg)
    {
        //add parameter checking here

        string path = path.MapPath("file.txt");
        //actual log goes here
    }
}
```

Note that now the test would be responsible to create the `IServerPath` instance, which can then use to inject the mock

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach using dependency injection.

```
public class FileLogger
{
    private readonly string _filePath;

    public FileLogger(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    public void Log(string msg)
    {
        //write to the log
    }
}
```

Now your logging class has a single responsibility - writing to the file. It is *not* responsible for figuring out which file to write to. It expects to have that value injected into it.

Also, I avoided using a `static` method. If the method is `static` then a similar problem occurs again: How do you test classes that depend on the logging class?

By making it non-static you can repeat the same pattern - mock the logger so that you can test classes that depend on it.

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string msg);
}
```

Then your logging class can implement the interface and you can inject that interface (instead of a concrete class) into classes that might need to write to a log.

[Here's a post](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/25/adapter-pattern.html) which demonstrates injecting a logger into a class. There are often better ways to accomplish the same purpose (like using an interceptor) but at least it prevents your code from having dependencies everywhere on some concrete class.